# Why are int 32 bits?

Tags: java, .net

Both in Java and .net the default int is 32 bit. Does it have to do with the fact that when java and .net came around, most processors in use were 32 bit? Or was there some other reason to choose 32 as the default bit length for integers?

Comment: I would argue that even now most processors that are running Java code are 32-bit - unless there are mobile phones with 64-bit CPUs onboard...

Comment: `long` or  `long int` used to represent 32 bits too...

Comment: There are 16-bit, 32-bit, and 64-bit integers in all those languages...what's the problem?

Comment: @AndrewMao i think developer747 is just curious, as I am

Comment: I believe that's a practical assumption. Having the default/basic types be of the same size as a processor register is ideal for performance reasons and I would expect it has been maintained as a backwards compatibility issue. Also, while our desktops and laptops may be learning towards 64-bit, that's not necessarily true of other hardware.

Comment: @kirugan ok, but `short`, `int`, and `long` just seems to make more sense and be more concise than `int`, `long`, and `long long`, etc.

Comment: Also, the CPU isn't the only consideration for performance.  With 32bit values, you can fit more into a Serialized message over I/O, fit more into a single cache-line, lots more...

Comment: Err, because it's a really good choice? Not constructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is mostly due to the fact that most processors were 32bit. This shows in other parts of the Java Specification as well. For instance, it is explicitly not guaranteed that `long` and `double` (64bit) reads and writes are atomic, while for all other primitive types it is.

Comment: your answer doesnt clear why 32 bit - is the (usual) size of int, nothing about cpu registers as well

Comment: It's 32 bit because a 32bit processor is most comfortable (i.e., efficient) with 32bit values. I don't know what else there is to explain.

Answer (score 2):

Java was based on C and some C++.

In C `char` is 8-bit, `short` is 16-bit and a `long long` is 64-bit.  An `int` could be 16-bit or 32-bit but for simplicity in Java they decided on `byte` being 8-bit, `short` is 16-bit, `int` is 32-bit and `long` is 64-bit. In Java `char` is 16-bit unsigned.

In short, from C there were four types and four sizes and so `int` ended up being 32-bit.

Comment: Is long long was available in the C89 (or smth...) ?

Comment: Note that none of those sizes are actually guaranteed for C or C++ either. They're just the most common implementations.